# Character encoding between Java (Linux) and Windows system

Tags: java, sockets, character-encoding

I have a simple program that makes a request to a remote server running a service which I believe is written in Delphi, but definately running on Windows.

I'm told the service will be using whatever the default encoding is for Windows.

When I get a response and use println to output it I'm getting some strange symbols in the output, which make me think it is a character encoding issue.

How can I tell Java the the input from the remote system is in the windows encoding?

I have tried the following:

```
_receive = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_socket.getInputStream(),"ISO-8859-1"));
_System.out.println(_receive.readLine());
```

The extra characters appear as squares in the output with 4 numbers in the square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you KNOW what the "default encoding" is, you can't tell what it is. The "default encoding" is generally the system-global codepage, which can be different on different systems.

You should really try to make people use an encoding that both sides agree on; nowadays, this should almost always be UTF-16 or UTF-8.

Btw, if you are sending one character on the Windows box, and you receive multiple "strange symbols" on the Java box, there's a good chance that the Windows box is already sending UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Use `cp1252` instead of `ISO-8859-1`, as it is default on windows.

Comment: Hint: CP1252 is merely ISO-8859-1 with a few additional characters; for most "real" data, if 8859-1 doesn't work then CP1252 won't help. Some software even treats ISO-8859-1 as CP1252, at least when reading data.